# Search a multidimensional array object's content using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, multidimensional-array

I have the following object:

```
public class RandomModel : Metadata
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ContentMod[][] Content { get; set; }

    public class ContentMod
    {
        public string Subtitle { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string[] List { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to search and return a RandomModel that contains a ContentMod that contains a string value input in any of its variables (Subtitle, Text, and/or List).

I am trying to do the equivalent of the following:

So if I want to search the string search input in the text of Name from the RandomModel and if it does contain the search string, return the RandomModel, I would do something like the following:

```
var randomContent = (from item in RandomContent
                     where item.Name.ToUpper().Contains(search)
                     select item).ToList();
```

Now I am trying to search text within all parameters of the ContentMod.

Something like the following:

```
var randomContent = (from item in RandomContent
                     where item.ContentMod.???.ToUpper().Contains(search)
                     select item).ToList();
```

I can't seem to figure out the ??? part above. How am I to use linq to iterate a multidimensional object's contents, and if they contain the string search, return the RandomModel.

Any help is much appreciated!
Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this bit of code if you don't mind using method syntax instead of query syntax.

```
var randomContent = models.Where(r => r.Content.Any(x =>
{
    return x.Any(y =>
    {
        return y.Text.ToUpper().Contains(search)
            || y.Subtitle.ToUpper().Contains(search)
            || y.List.Any(z => z.ToUpper().Contains(search));
    });
})).ToList();
```

I usually use `IndexOf` to do case insensitive searches, so in that case it would look like this.

```
var randomContent = models.Where(r => r.Content.Any(x =>
{
    return x.Any(y =>
    {
        return y.Text.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
        || y.Subtitle.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
        || y.List.Any(z => z.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    });
})).ToList();
```

You can adust the `StringComparison` as needed.

Edit: As pointed out by Backs in the comments, `SelectMany` can be used to give you this.

```
var randomContent = models.Select(r => r.Content.SelectMany(o => o.Where(x =>
{
    return x.Text.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
        || x.Subtitle.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
        || x.List.Any(y => y.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
}))).ToList();
```

Comment: `r.Content.SelectMany(o => o)` can simplify expression